# How can I pass mock data through the API response

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my front end needs following JSON response,

```
{
    "status": "000",
    "message": "",
    "validation": [],
    "data": {
        "TeacherGroup": [
            {           
                "TeacherCode": "BP",
                "TeacherCount": "12",
                "img": "",
                "salary": "50000.00"
            },
            {           
                "TeacherCode": "FT",
                "TeacherCount": "5",
                "img": "",
                "salary": "165090.50"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

For the testing purpose, I need to make mock data according to create this JSON response. I have created class according to this JSON as follows.

```
public class TeacherGroup
{
    public string TeacherCode { get; set; }
    public string TeacherCount { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public string salary { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<TeacherGroup> TeacherGroup { get; set; }
}

public class TeacherGroupData
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<object> validation { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do that, I tried this way to set mock data,

```
public IEnumerable<TeacherGroupData> GetAllGroups()
{
    var groups = new List<TeacherGroupData>()
    {
        new TeacherGroupData{ status = "000" , message = "" , validation = null }
        
        // how can I set values to data > TeacherGroup
    };

    return groups;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? if yes, how can I set mock values to data and TeacherGroup?

Comment: It looks like you're already setting values to three of the properties on your object.  What's stopping you from setting a value to the fourth property?  Basically just adding `data = new Data { }` to your object initializer?  And further adding property initializers within `new Data { }` as needed?  I guess it's not clear to me what the problem is here and why you can't just keep going with the code you've started writing?

Comment: @David Sir, I just wanted to verify, is this the correct approach to set mock data to get that response.

Comment: In that case the answer is simply "yes, this is *a* correct approach to return mock data from an API".  Though you can also verify this by running and testing your code.

Comment: @David Cool, thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some requirements regarding mocked data, you can use this sample code:

```
public static TeacherGroupData GetMockData(int teachersGroupCount)
{
    var teacherGroup = new TeacherGroup[teachersGroupCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < teachersGroupCount; i++)
        teacherGroup[i] = new TeacherGroup()
        {
            TeacherCode= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            TeacherCount = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            salary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            img = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        };

    var mockData = new TeacherGroupData()
    {
        status = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        validation = new List<object>(),
        data = new Data() { TeacherGroup = teacherGroup.ToList() },
    };

    return mockData;
}
```

Well, for testing purposes (unit test) there's library AutoFixture which can be used also here (usually it is used in unit tests, but you have similair situation). This greatly simplifies the code:

```
public static TeacherGroupData GetMockData(int teachersGroupCount)
{
    var data = new Data()
    {
        TeacherGroup = new Fixture().CreateMany<TeacherGroup>(teachersGroupCount).ToList(),
    };

    var mockData = new Fixture().Create<TeacherGroupData>();
    mockData.data = data;

    return mockData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is not test safe*, but you could desialize the json to the object using json.net

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

```
string testDataJson = @"{
  {
    "status": "000",
    "message": "",
    "validation": [],
   .......
}";

var teacherGroupData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TeacherGroupData>(testDataJson);
```